# Как не вставлять данные в таблицу, если они УЖЕ в ней есть?

Tags: python, postgresql

У меня есть следующая информация об играх НХЛ, которую я добавляю в таблицу games. Таблицу games я создаю следующим запросом:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS games (GAMEDATE DATE NOT NULL, AWAY_TEAM varchar(32), HOME_TEAM varchar(32), SCORES varchar(32))')

for line in all_stlouis_games_list:
    sql_string = """ INSERT INTO games (GAMEDATE, AWAY_TEAM, HOME_TEAM, SCORES) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT  DO NOTHING"""
    record_to_insert = tuple(line)
    cur.execute(sql_string, record_to_insert)
    conn.commit()
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в таблицу не вставлялись уже существующие в ней записи. Допустим, если в таблице уже есть `2022-01-08  Washington Capitals St. Louis Blues 6`, то данная строка не будет помещаться в таблицу снова.
Я пытался воспользоваться ON CONFLICT, но никакого результата это мне не дало. Я не до конца понимаю, как оно работает, судя по всему, работаете при совпадении уникальных id.
Возможно, я могу воспользоваться INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT FROM games WHERE...) но точно не знаю как правильно это сделать в моем случае.

```
2022-01-08  Washington Capitals St. Louis Blues 6
2022-01-09  Dallas Stars    St. Louis Blues 3
2022-01-14  Seattle Kraken  St. Louis Blues 3
2022-01-16  Toronto Maple Leafs St. Louis Blues 11
2022-01-18  Nashville Predators St. Louis Blues 8
2022-01-08  Washington Capitals St. Louis Blues 6
2022-01-09  Dallas Stars    St. Louis Blues 3
2022-01-14  Seattle Kraken  St. Louis Blues 3
2022-01-16  Toronto Maple Leafs St. Louis Blues 11
2022-01-18  Nashville Predators St. Louis Blues 8
```

Comment: что бы on conflict сработал надо что бы конфликт появился. А это возможно только если вы при создании таблицы создали на ней соответствующий уникальный или первичный ключ. https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/ddl-constraints#ddl-constraints-unique-constraints

Comment: @Mike т.е. конфликт может быть только по уникальному ключу, верно? id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY?
Я так понимаю, что это не совсем мой вариант, т.к ключ у двух одинаковых записей будет разный, он же создается автоматически и инкрементируется.
Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: *конфликт может быть только по уникальному ключу, верно?* Верно. Но уникальный ключ (1) не обязан быть PRIMARY KEY (2) может быть композитным (т.е. включать несколько полей или даже выражений). В данном случае поможет `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON games (GAMEDATE, AWAY_TEAM, HOME_TEAM);`. Для правильной работы ограничения уникальности поля AWAY_TEAM и HOME_TEAM следует объявить как NOT NULL.

Comment: @Akina, работает! Благодарю